# Changing JQuery function from keyup to submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not overly familiar with jquery and I'm trying to adapt someone else's code for what I need. Currently, the code submits the contents of a form with a textarea (called "sendie") and other information when the user presses the enter key. I'd like to change that so that the information is submitted when a button is pressed. It seems like it should be simple, but it has me completely stumped. I'm an amateur, this is for a personal project for some friends and I. Any help would be appreciated.

Relevant Code (I think):

```
// watch textarea for release of key press

    $('#sendie').keyup(function(e) {    
                                 
        if (e.keyCode == 13) { 
                  
           var text = $(this).val();
           var maxLength = $(this).attr("maxlength");  
           var length = text.length; 
                     
           // send 
           if (length <= maxLength + 1) { 
                     
               chat.send(text, name, time, filename,);  
               $(this).val("");
                        
           } else {
                    
               $(this).val(text.substring(0, maxLength));
                        
                }                   
            }
        });
```

```
<form id="send-message-area">
    <textarea id="sendie" maxlength='5000'></textarea>
    <br>
    <input id="post" type="submit" value="Post" /> //I added this line for the button.
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery I think you can just do:

```
$("#post").click(function() {
    var text = $("#sendie").val();
    var maxLength = $("#sendie").attr("maxlength");
    //rest of the code in the if block from the original, replacing $(this) with $("#sendie")
});
```

This adds a click handler to the button you added with `id="post"`. You might not want it to be a `submit` type though and rather do `button` type, but I'm not 100% on that and/or your exact use-case.

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much. I had to add a hidden value to the form to pass the logged in character name, but otherwise, it now works perfectly.